# How to select multiple files using Ctrl key in list `<li>` element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We are implementing our own browse as there are certain limitations with existing HTML browse. In HTML browse we can select multiple files by pressing Ctrl key, we want to implement similar functionality in our custom browse.

```
  <div style="width: 387px; height: 300px; padding-top:5px;margin-right:10px; border: 1px solid white; ">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="folders in folderList">
              <button ng-attr-id="{{ 'object-' + $index}}"
                      style="cursor:pointer;border: 0px solid white; border-radius: 0px; padding-left: 30px;height:auto;margin-bottom: 5px;"
                      class="button btn-bgc bgc-hover"
                      data-ng-click="getFolderList($index)">
                  {{folders.name}}
               <i class="fa fa-hdd-o"
                  ng-if="folders.type === 'Device'"
                  style="display: inline; float:left; padding: 2px; color: #D3D3D3;margin-left: -30px;"
                  aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <i class="fa fa-folder-open"
                  ng-if="folders.type === 'folder'"
                  style="display: inline; float:left; padding: 2px; color: #FFE4B5;margin-left: -30px;"
                  aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <i class="fa fa-file-o"
                  ng-if="folders.type === 'file'"
                  style="display: inline; float:left; padding: 2px; margin-left: -30px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </button>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

In my application on selecting folder it opens the folder, on selecting files it just selects the file for future use. In the sample plunker created I have 2 folders and 3 files. Here at a time I can select only one file. How can I select multiple files by pressing ctrl(similar to windows file selection) and display those selected files on click of "Display Selected Files" button.Hre is link to the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/REBtXPSH8sa0cvYvp9A4?p=preview

Please let me know if any other information is needed. Any help is appreciated.

// Code goes here

```
var testController = angular.module('test', []);

testController.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {


  $scope.folderList = [{name:"folder1",type:"folder"},{name:"folder2",type:"folder"},{name:"file1.txt",type:"file"},{name:"file2.txt",type:"file"},{name:"file3.txt",type:"file"}];

  $scope.resetBackground = function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.folderList.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById('object-' + i).style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        }

  $scope.getFolderList = function (index) {
    $scope.resetBackground();
    $document.on('keypress', function (event) {
              if(event.keyCode == 17) { // 17 - Ctrl
                  // need to select multiple files here.
              }

      })
    document.getElementById('object-' + index).style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
  }; 

}]);
```

Comment: With `ng-click`,  Event object is available as `$event`. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions - $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're violating some fundamental angularJS principles in your code (like direct DOM manipulation, interaction with global `document` variable), so I would suggest to familiarize yourself with these first: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

To solve your issue:

In your HTML, pass the clickEvent into your `getFolderList` method:

```
data-ng-click="getFolderList($event, $index)"
```

In your controller, check whether the `ctrlKey` flag is true

```
$scope.getFolderList = function (clickEvent, index) {
  if (clickEvent.ctrlKey) {
    // ctrlKey is pressed while clicking
  } else {
    $scope.resetBackground();  
  }

  document.getElementById('object-' + index).style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
};
```

See a plunkr at https://plnkr.co/edit/QLwZuQa3AHdelJKFSIkL?p=preview (this also does multi-select for the `metaKey` on macOS systems)

Comment: Thanks!! Am new to Angular JS and will definitely need to look into the document and am not aware of clickEvent.ctrlKey too.